# Given the equation $\alpha \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$, solve for $\mathbf{v}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm reading a textbook at the moment that provides the following linear equation,

$$
\alpha \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b},
$$
and asks to solve for $\mathbf{v}$. The form of $\mathbf{v}$ is given as
$$
\mathbf{v} = \frac{\alpha^2 \mathbf{b} - \alpha (\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}) + (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{a}}{\alpha(\alpha^2+\lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert^2)}.
$$

It's easy enough to verify that this is the correct solution. However, I can't figure out how I'd solve for $\mathbf{v}$ if given just the original equation.

Are there any general approaches to solving this kind of equation systematically?

Edit: $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are all vectors, whereas $\alpha$ is a scalar such that $\alpha \neq 0$.

Comment: a systematic approach is to take the scalar product of the equation with **a** and then the cross-product also with **a** and eliminate terms

Comment: @DavidQuinn Mixed product with two equal vectors is null  if I remember well. I am agree with you.

Comment: why do you call this a linear equation?

Comment: @David Quinn is correct. He means there should be two equations: one by cross product and other by scalar.

Comment: if a and b are not parallel, then a,b, b x a, is a basis of R^3. so v=v1 a+v2 b+v3 (b x a). Maybe one can deduce v1,v2,v3 from this

Comment: Which textbook is that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking cross product with $\mathbf{a}$ on both sides, we get,
\begin{align*}
&\alpha \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}\\
\implies &\alpha(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{a})+(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{a})\times \mathbf{a}=\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a}\\
\implies &\alpha(\mathbf{b}-\alpha \mathbf{v})+(\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{a})\mathbf{a}-|a|^2\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a}\\
\implies &\alpha \mathbf{b}-\alpha^2\mathbf{v}+\dfrac1\alpha (\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a})\mathbf{a}-|a|^2\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a}&&\Big(\text{Using }\alpha (\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{a})=\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a}\Big)
\end{align*}
Now solve for $\mathbf{v}$ directly.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I missed the substitution in the third line when trying for myself.